# Sharing links with accompanying thumbnail on your own site

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, twitter

I need some direction. I'm building a social media site with django and I'm trying to design it like twitter/facebook, so that when someone posts a link - say from the New York Times - it displays the headline of the article along with the accompanying thumbnail. Problem is: I don't even know what this is called, or how to begin. Can someone point me in the right direction? Even just a term I can google to learn more?[image]

Comment: It's called reading meta information

Answer (score 3):

This is called Meta tags and OpenGraph tags. You can add meta tags for general usage and Open Graph tags would help you with customising previews of websites such as Facebook and Twitter.

You need to add meta and og(OpenGraph) tags to your website header section. See example meta tag below,

```html
  <meta name="description" content="My website description">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Some,Tags,Here">
  <meta name="author" content="Your Name">
```

Please note that OpenGraph isn't supported by all content sharing platforms. Some do use Meta tags to generate their preview.

See some example OG tags below,

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```

You can read more about OG here https://ogp.me/

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Open Graph Protocol](https://ogp.me/).

The Open Graph protocol enables any web page to become a rich object in a social graph. For instance, this is used on Facebook to allow any web page to have the same functionality as any other object on Facebook.

Basically the way it works you add some `meta tags` to your HTML and social channels will read that and act accordingly to the functionality desired.

Basic usage: ( taken from Open Graph site )

```
og:title - The title of your object as it should appear within the graph, e.g., "The Rock".
og:type - The type of your object, e.g., "video.movie". Depending on the type you specify, other properties may also be required.
og:image - An image URL which should represent your object within the graph.
og:url - The canonical URL of your object that will be used as its permanent ID in the graph, e.g., "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/".
```

Then adding the meta tags should be something like:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```